# MS SQL - Combine two Integer columns as Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, integer

I have a TDate column for date. I would like to group my data by month and year so in my select query, I have columns TMonth and TYear (Select DATEPART(mm, TDate) as TMonth, DATEPART(yyyy, TDate) As TYear from MyTable). Both are now integers. Now, I would like to combine it in one column using a select query with mm/dd/yyyy format. dd should be the last day of TMonth.

How can it be done using a select sql query? Please help. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

"Modern" SQL Server versions, since 2012, have a [`datefromparts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) function you could use to create a date:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(TYear, TMonth, 1)
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Got it by using 
SELECT  DATEPART(mm, TDate) as TMonth, DATEPART(yyyy, TDate) As TYear ,
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, TDate) + 1, 0)) From MyTable